# My goal is to upload data from an excel file that may have random number of columns to postgreSQL

Tags: java, excel, postgresql, primefaces, xhtml

Example: my excel contain 10 columns and my database has 15 columns and it will still upload even if there will be 5 empty columns.

The code I'm using can upload the excel but it gets an error when the cell in empty.

Tools/language I'm using(I don't think all of them matter here): xhtml , Java, Tomcat, PostgreSQl, Primefaces

Thanks in advance for your help.

here is the code I am using:

```
    public void upload() throws IOException{

    String host="localhost";
    String port="5432";
    String db_name="postgres";
    String username="postgres";
    String password="postgres";

    int max = 1000;
    int min = 0;
    String dir="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\book1.xlsx";

    int batchSize = 20;
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dir);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+db_name+"", ""+username+"", ""+password+"");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO survey.tabledata (id,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,surveyid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);    

        int count = 0;
    
        //rowIterator.next(); // skip the header row

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            
                Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();

                int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();

                switch (columnIndex) {

                case 0:
                    int col1 = (int) nextCell.getNumericCellValue(); 
                    statement.setInt(1,col1);
                    break;

                case 1:

                    String col2 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(2, col2);
                    break;

                case 2:

                    String col3 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(3, col3);
                    break;

                case 3:

                    String col4 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(4, col4);
                    break;

                case 4:

                    String col5 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(5, col5);
                    break;

                case 5:

                    String col6 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(6, col6);
                    break;

                case 6:

                    String col7 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(7, col7);
                    break;
                case 7:

                    String col8 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(8, col8);
                    break;
                case 8:

                    String col9 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(9, col9);
                    break;

                case 9:

                    String col10 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(10, col10);
                    break;

                case 10:
                    String col11 = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
                    statement.setString(11, col11);
                    break;

                case 11:
                    int col12 = (int) nextCell.getNumericCellValue();
                    statement.setInt(12,col12);
                    break;

                }
            }
            statement.addBatch();

            if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                statement.executeBatch();
            }              
        }
        // workbook.close();
        // execute the remaining queries
        statement.executeBatch();

        connection.commit();
        connection.close();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Import done in %d ms\n", (end - start));

    } catch (IOException ex1) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
        ex1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException ex2) {
        System.out.println("Database error");
        ex2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will give you an error because you are casting a null or empty value.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: You can add an if condition like if nextCell.getNumericCellValue() == null or empty then just make it zero, or if it is nullable, use the nullable types. Just avoid type casting a null or empty value.

Comment: I found another method. Basically I am using Jsf for my project and I'm using a similar code. So now even if my columns are empty it is still uploading. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Even though your error message is not in your question's description, I am guessing you have a `null` exception on your Database.

You could solve it like this:

```java
String col = nextCell.getStringCellValue();
if(col == null)
{
    col = "";
}

statement.setString(1, col);
```